# When I try to install teiid in domain mode, teiid-jdbc socket-binging portall 31000 is not opened

Tags: teiid

My server group is using ha-sockets, and configuration in domain.xml is as following, after start server and slave, ss -lnap check the opened port, 31000 is not in list.

```
 <socket-binding-group name="ha-sockets" default-interface="public">
        <socket-binding name="ajp" port="${jboss.ajp.port:8009}"/>
        <socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}"/>
        <socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}"/>
        <socket-binding name="jgroups-mping" interface="private" multicast-address="${jboss.default.multicast.address:230.0.0.4}" multicast-port="45700"/>
        <socket-binding name="jgroups-tcp" interface="private" port="7600"/>
        <socket-binding name="jgroups-tcp-fd" interface="private" port="57600"/>
        <socket-binding name="jgroups-udp" interface="private" port="55200" multicast-address="${jboss.default.multicast.address:230.0.0.4}" multicast-port="45688"/>
        <socket-binding name="jgroups-udp-fd" interface="private" port="54200"/>
        <socket-binding name="modcluster" multicast-address="${jboss.modcluster.multicast.address:224.0.1.105}" multicast-port="23364"/>
        <socket-binding name="teiid-jdbc" interface="public"  port="31000"/>
        <socket-binding name="teiid-odbc" port="35432"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
        <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
            <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
        </outbound-socket-binding>
    </socket-binding-group>
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: It may be worth adding a language tag to this (Java?) as this tag is liable to only see a small readership.

Answer (score 0):

Typically there is port offset defined with multiple instances, check to see what that is then typically that will be 31000+offset